# Can only add one item in cart CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

I cant seem to add any more items and the latest one I add replaces the existing one.

```
public function addcart(){
    if(isset($this->session->userdata)){
        $type = $this->session->userdata('type');
        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
         $this->db->select('id_product ,price');
         $query = $this->db->get('product', array('title'=> $this->input->post('title')));

         if($query->num_rows() >0){
            $row = $query->row();
            $data = array(
            'id'     => $row->id_product,
           'qty'     => $this->input->post('quantity'),
           'price'   => $row->price,
           'name'    => $this->input->post('title'),
           //'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
        );

        $this->cart->insert($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show the `cart::insert()` method which is likely where your problem lies, as it seems clear you are able to select that item from the database and place it in the cart. My guess is the insert method is overwriting what is in the cart and not adding to it.

Comment: Are you storing your session data in database, or you are using cookies. Note that cookie size limit is only 4kB.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function addcart(){
    if(isset($this->session->userdata)){
        $type = $this->session->userdata('type');
        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
         $this->db->select('id_product ,price');
         $query = $this->db->get('product', array('title'=> $this->input->post('title')));

        $cart['product'] = $this->cart->contents(); // get previous data from cart
         if($query->num_rows() >0){
            $row = $query->row();
            $id = $row->id_product;
            $cart['product'][$id] = array(
            'id'     => $row->id_product,
           'qty'     => $this->input->post('quantity'),
           'price'   => $row->price,
           'name'    => $this->input->post('title'),
           //'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
        );

        $this->cart->insert($cart); //update cart
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't display anything

Answer (score 0):

controller :

```
$code = $this->input->post("idwheel");
$nama = $this->input->post("namawheel");
$base = $this->input->post("basewheel");
$desc = $this->input->post("descwheel");
$amountdefault = $this->input->post("amountwheel");
$data = array(
 'id'      => $code,
 'qty'     => 1,
 'amountdefault'     => $amountdefault,
 'price'   => $base,
 'name'    => $nama,
  'desc'    => $desc
    );

$this->cart->insert($data);
redirect("selling",'refresh');
```

and view

```
<?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $items['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $items['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $items['desc']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

i hope this can help